# Intersection of two function vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to crack this question down but I can't even begin and don't know where to look. Hopefully some of you may shine some light.

$Let \ W_1 = \{f \in \mathfrak{F}({\Bbb R}); \ f \ is \ even\} \ and \ W_2 = \{f \in \mathfrak{F}({\Bbb R}); \ f \ is \ odd\} \ be \ subspaces \ of \ \mathfrak{F}({\Bbb R})$.  Calculate $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Only $f\equiv0$ belongs to both $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Comment: So every function that is odd or even and goes through the origin, for example? How would I describe that? Thanks for spending your time answering the question, by the way.

Comment: The only function which is odd and eleven is equal to zero (it is easy from a definition).

Comment: Ohhhh, I see it now... I didn't realize that. Thanks a lot for pointing it out. :)

Comment: You are welcome! (And "eleven" certainly means "even").